# How to efficiently scale up video frame using NDK

Tags: android, c++, video, android-ndk, multimedia

I am doing an Android project about dealing with video frame, I need to handle every frame before display it. The process includes scaling up frames from 1920x1080 to 2560x1440 resolution, color space conversion and some necessary image processing based on RGB, and all these works should be finished within 33ms~40ms.

I have optimized the yuv->rgb and other processing with arm neon, they worked well. But I have to scale up frame firstly from 1080p to 2k resolution, it's the bottleneck of performance now.

My question is how to efficiently scale up image from 1080p to 2k resolution within 20ms, I don't have much experience about scaling algorithm, so any suggestions are helpful.
Could I use arm neon to optimize the existing algorithm?

The hardware environment:

- CPU: Samsung Exynos 5420
- Memory: 3GB
- Display: 2560X1600 px

**Update:**

I will describe my decoding process, I use MediaCodec to decode the normal video(H.264) to YUV(NV12), the default decoder is hardware, it's very fast. Then I use arm neon to convert NV12 to RGBW, and then send RGBW frame to surfaceflinger to display. I just use normal SurfaceView rahter than GLSurfaceView.

The bottleneck is how to scale up YUV from 1080p to 2K fast.

Comment: Why do you need to scale up?

Comment: @AlexCohn It's the requirement, and I need to deal with a special RGB type(Pentile RGBW) which is not recognized by surfaceflinger, so I need to scale up the frame first, and deal with every pixel of 2560x1600, and then post the frame to display. If I let surfaceflinger do scaling up, it will lose some information. Do you have any idea about this question?

Comment: I believe that the hardware color convertor/scaler will do the job much faster and probably better than CPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexCohn, I am trying to find the hardware solution to do this. I could ensure that Android hardware composer uses the hardware to up-scaling, but I am not sure that we could do the same thing in Application.

Comment: maybe you can use OpenGL?

Comment: Are you familiar with OpenGL and shader programming? This does sound like a good problem to throw at parallel GPU hardware. Let me know if you want to go down this path because this sounds interesting.

Comment: @AlexCohn I'm not familiar with OpenGL --!, I need to google some docs.

Comment: @MultimediaMike I'm not really familiar with OpenGL and shader, I guess I should start the OpenGL and shader from now on. Do you have any advice? Thanks a lot guys, your suggestions are very helpful for me.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to describe a bit more about the pipeline. This is my first exposure to RGBW colorspace (though I am reading about it). Do you get a normal video (like H.264) and receive the frames as raw YUV, then convert the YUV -> RGBW, then upscale the RGBW and then blit? Or does the decoded video carry some of the RGBW information? How is the video decoded? In software or hardware?

Comment: @MultimediaMike Hi mike, I have updated the question, and I have a question about RGBW, do you know how to add saturation when convert yuv to rgbw? Or I must add saturation based on rgb? I found that the rgbw lose some saturation after conversion from NV12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that examples work well, so allow me to lead with this example program that uses OpenGL shaders to convert from YUV -> RGB: http://www.fourcc.org/source/YUV420P-OpenGL-GLSLang.c

What I envision for your program is:

1. Hardware video decodes H.264 stream -> YUV array
2. Upload that YUV array as a *texture* to OpenGL; actually, you will upload 3 different textures-- Y, U, and V
3. Run a fragment shader that converts those Y, U, and V textures into an RGB(W) image; this will produce a new texture in video memory
4. Run a new fragment shader against the texture generated in previous step in order to scale the image

There might be a bit of a learning curve involved here, but I think it's workable, given your problem description. Take it one step at a time: get the OpenGL framework in place, try uploading just the Y texture and writing a naive fragment shader that just emits a grayscale pixel based on the Y sample, then move onto correctly converting the image, then get a really naive upsampler working, then put a more sophisticated upsampler into service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend opengl es too, mainly because of the project I'm currently working on, also playing video. For me, the display is 1920 x 1080, so the texture I'm using is 2048 x 1024. I get approx 35 fps on a quad core arm7.

Use a GLSurfaceView and your own custom renderer. If you're using ffmpeg then once you've decoded your video frames, use sws_scale to scale your frame and then just upload it into the opengl texture. The larger your texture/display, the less fps you will get because it a lot of time taken uploading large images to the gpu every frame.

Depending on your needs for decoding your video input is what you will have to research. For me, I had to compile ffmpeg for android and start from there.

Comment: Actually I tested the sws_scale method in ffmepg, it's a little slow for me. The test result is about 40ms per frame from 1080p to 2K, so I think it's the best if there is some hardware solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm moving away from sws_scale for the next update of the project. I will basically convert the decoded frame to rgba and use UV to clip the texture for display. GL can do the scaling in hardware when its displayed. A 720x576 frame will simply use a 1024x1024 texture and only needs one upload per frame. There's probably little you can do with filtering apart from the options GL gives you but that should be sufficient enough. The only issue I have at the moment is the need to de-interlace each frame so I'm looking into glsl to do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

my apologies for putting this in an answer. i dont have enough points to make a comment. 
I'd like to add that you might run into OGL texture limitations. I have tried to use OGL for the opposite problem; scaling down from the camera in real time. the problem is that the max OGL texture is 2048x2048. Not sure if this is true for all devices. this limit was true on newer kit like N72013 and LG2. in the end, i had to write in in the NDK without OGL by optimising the hell out of it by hand.
good luck, though.